# Which of both ways for solving this exercise is more efficient?

Tags: sql, performance

So, this is the exercise:

*Make a query that displays the number of presidents (job_id AD_PRES), the total salary sum of the presidents, the number of administration vice presidents (job_id AD_VP), and the total salary sum of those vice presidents.*

The way it was shown to me:

```
Select count(decode(job_id,'AD_PRES',1,0)) AS NumOfPres,
Sum(decode(job_id,'AD_PRES',salary,0) AS SumSalaryP,
count(decode(job_id,'AD_VP',1,0)) AS NumOfPres,
Sum(decode(job_id,'AD_VP',salary,0) AS SumSalaryVP
FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

This is what I did:

```
Select count (e.job_id),sum(e.salary),count(m.job_id),sum(m.salary)
FROM employees e join employees m on(e.job_id=m.job_id)
Where e.job_id='AD_PRES'
AND m.job_id='AD_VP';
```

So, join is more readable I would say but is there any other performance difference?

Comment: well, query #2 will return `0,0,0,0` and query #1 uses legacy syntax `decode` vs. `case` (and returns a wrong count, too :-)

Comment: Example 1 seems to be completely wrong since the `()`s don't seem to be balanced.

Answer (score 0):

Your join is forcing the relationship between the employees. If there is no such relationship then all results would return 0.

Also you are linking all employees that are president with all employees that are vice-president. So if you have 3 presidents and 10 vicepresidents, the join will result in 30 rows and the sum will be repeated to calculate the total, something that would never happen in the first query.

Comment: No, the join will return zero rows.

Comment: @dnoeth and the count will be 0, the sum `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

The exercise didn't specify *return a single row*, so the simple way is:

```
Select 
   job_id, 
   count(*),
   sum(salary)
FROM EMPLOYEES
where job_id in ('AD_PRES', 'AD_VP')
group by job_id
```

The 1st Select uses legacy syntax and will not return a correct result as `count(decode(job_id,'AD_PRES',1,0))` is the same as `count(*)`.

And it's reading all rows, there should be a WHERE:

```
Select 
   sum(case when job_id = 'AD_PRES' then 1 else 0 end) AS NumOfPres,
   Sum(case when job_id = 'AD_PRES' then salary else 0 end) AS SumSalaryP,
   sum(case when job_id = 'AD_VP' then 1 else 0 end) AS  AS NumOfVPs,
   Sum(case when job_id = 'AD_PRES' then salary else 0 end) AS SumSalaryVP
FROM EMPLOYEES
where job_id in ('AD_PRES', 'AD_VP');
```

Your 2nd Select doesn't work at all. You join on matching job_ids, but one is 'AD_PRES' and the other 'AD_VP', so no match.

When you want to join it would be a CROSS JOIN:

```
Select *
from 
 ( Select 
      count(*) AS NumOfPres,
      sum(salary) AS SumSalaryP
   FROM EMPLOYEES
   where job_id ='AD_PRES'
 )
cross join
 ( Select 
      count(*) AS NumOfVPs,
      sum(salary) AS SumSalaryVP
   FROM EMPLOYEES
   where job_id ='AD_VP'
 )
```